# Map All columns if data exist after particular column

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on consolidation of all sheets and map previously consolidated status,

I have one code which is working perfectly till consolidation, now I need a code to `vlookup` a status from previous consolidated sheet to current consolidated sheet.

This is previous consolidated sheet:

[image: This is previous consolidated sheet]

Current consolidated sheet:

[image: Current consolidated sheet:]

I want to map if data is there after column C in previous sheet with headings to current sheet starting from D column. I am able to map column D with my code but I need to map rest of the non-blank columns also.

This is my Code as of now:

```
Sub FMEA_Consolidate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy") 
      
    'Rename last consolidated as old if exist:
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "latest", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Sheets("Consolidated").Activate
            Range("D1") = ws.Name
            Range("D1").Interior.Color = 65535
            ws.Name = "old"
        End If
    Next
    
    'If Last Old exist then Map previous status:
    Dim Lastws As Worksheet
    For Each Lastws In Sheets
        If InStr(1, Lastws.Name, "old", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then      
            Sheets("Consolidated").Activate
            Range("D2").Select    
            Selection.FormulaArray = _
                "=IFERROR(INDEX(Old!C[-1],MATCH((RC[-2]&RC[-3])," + _
                "Old!C[-2]&Old!C[-3]),0),0),0)"
            Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & Range("A" & _
                Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & Range("D2:D" & _
                Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).Copy
            Range("D2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Sheets("old").Delete
        End If
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Latest Consolidated " & SheetName
    Range("D2").Select
End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Cross Post 1](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/map-all-columns-if-data-exist-after-particular-column.39604/)

[Cross Post 2](https://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1243321&p=4964474#post4964474)

Comment: What did you try to do what you asked for and where are your difficulties? Please show the code you tried and tell us what is wrong with it, where you got stuck or errors. Because this is no free code writing service people here will kindly help to improve or fix your code but it's unlikely that they will do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Comment: Hi Pᴇʜ, Thanks for your response, as you suggested i have updated my code.

Comment: Create a key using columns A & B in both sheets and use that for VLOOKUP of data. The layout of your previous consolidated sheet  is also not ideal for adding new data as you have to move the existing columns to add a new period in. It would be easier to add new periods to the end. I guess this was a deliberate choice for views reading from latest period to older periods.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Thanks for your response,  we do this activity daily hence will keep on add previous status columns in previous consolidated sheet.